# How can I route all of my Macs traffic through browsermob proxy in code?

Tags: macos, proxy, ios-simulator, browsermob

I'm trying to automate some tests on an iOS simulator, and I want to route traffic through browsermob proxy. As you can't set a proxy on the simulator, I think the best approach would be to route all of the traffic on the Mac it is running on through the proxy. How could I do this (through code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the standalone proxy and interacted with it via code using the REST API.